# How to execute a closure function and populate an array passed by reference in PHP

Tags: php, closures

I am trying to use PHP closures for the first time.

I wrote a small function that will take an array and a function in it's parameter. Its job is to loop through the giving array and it executes the $function on each element.

Here is my function

```
/**
 * It check each item in a giving array for a property called 'controllers', 
 * when exists it executes the $handler method on it
 * 
 * @param array $items
 * @param function $handler
 */
protected function addSubControls($items, $handler)
{
    foreach( $items as $item){
        if( property_exists($item, 'controllers')){
            //At this point we know this item has a sub controller listed under it, add it to the list
            foreach($item->controllers as $subControl){
                $handler( $subControl );
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now I want to use this function in 2 ways.

**First:** execute the method `generateHtmlValues()` on every item within the giving array. This works with no issues.

```
$this->addSubControls($control->items, function($subControl){
    $this->generateHtmlValues( $subControl );
});
```

**Second:** I want to add each qualifying item to an array that is being used outside that closure method.

```
$controls = ['a','b','c'];
$this->addSubControls($control->items, function($subControl) use(&$controls) {
    $controls[] = $subControl->id;
});
var_dump($controls);
```

at this point I am expecting that the `$controls` array to have 1 more value that what the original one is set to. But it is not doing that.

What am I missing here? How can the closure populate the array that I pass by reference?

Comment: as a side note, you might be interested in `array_map()` http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php

Comment: @Calimero thank you for that note. That sound very similar than what I am trying to do. so for my senario 1 how would I use array_map? `array_map($this->generateHtmlValues, $control->items);`?

Comment: Have you tried an `echo()` or `error_log()` call within `addSubControls()` or the closure, to ensure things are being called as expected?

Comment: @Mike A first pay attention to the callback syntax (one argument - the current array item, returns the modified item), which is the first argument to array_map(), second the array you want to loop over (or more if desired).

Answer (score 0):

After all, my code works correctly.

I was looking at the wrong output.

I will keep this question hoping it will help someone else.